# Boolean method would not return correctly

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I am studying Java and trying to make a little game of life game, but i have a problem with one of my methods returning a value that's supposed to change when the if statement is met.
Here's the code:

```
    int cont=0;
    while (!meetscondition(s,condition, cont)){
        cont++;
    }

    public boolean meetscondition(Scanner s,StringBuilder condition, int cont){
    boolean valid= false;

    switch (cont){
        case 0: 
            System.out.println("Something something");
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Something if they repeat the mistake"); 
            break;
    }

    condition.append(s.next());

    if (condition.toString() == "something"){
        valid = true;
    }

    return valid;

}
```

The condition is never met, i've tried to make a String instead of the StringBuilder but it acts the same, as if the if were not there.
Somehow the loop never ends even if you enter "something" the boolean is still false, so clearly something's not working as intended.
Thanks for the read.

Comment: Change `condition.toString() == "something"` to `"something".equals(condition.toString())`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong syntax but in my code it's still not working. I tried equals yesterday but was so tired that i forgot.